# Python click Js link with selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping

Iam tested webscraping the page:http://www.guiadosquadrinhos.com/todas-capas-disponiveis

I need navigate in pagination geting info pages favorite.
I need click link javascript next page:

javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lstProfileView$dataPagerNumeric2$ctl02$ctl00')

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:\Python27\Tools\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe')
driver.get("http://www.guiadosquadrinhos.com/todas-capas-disponiveis")
#print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("numero_capinha")[0].text)
#driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next_last")[0].click()
#time.sleep(5)
print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("numero_capinha")[0].text)
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next_last")[0].click()
print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("numero_capinha")[0].text)
```

My code return:

> sobreontem - Independente
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "teste_selenium.py", line 10, in 
>   driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next_last")[0].click()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 74, in click
>   self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 453, in _execute
>   return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 201, in execute
>   self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 181, in check_response
>   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
>   {"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be
>   manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"81","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:63160","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\":
>   \"5d3cfdc0-5d3b-11e5-b784-67706273a0bb\", \"id\":
>   \":wdc:1442494581220\"}","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/5d3cfdc0-5d3b-11e5-b784-67706273a0bb/element/%3Awdc%3A1442494581220/click"}}
>   Screenshot: available via screen

Whats is problem ?

Comment: Please post the html of the relevant `next_last` element. It seems it is not currently visible on the text page and you will have to execute some javascript to bring it to visibility.

Comment: <a class="next_last" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lstProfileView$dataPagerNumeric2$ctl02$ctl00','')">&gt;</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, you are doing the following -

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next_last")[0].click()
```

If you look in the source, there are multiple elements with this class name and the first one is disabled, because that is for the previous button and you are on first page.

Comment: Is true! Thanks, resolved my problem,
Solved this code:
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next_last")[2].click()